# NullReferenceException when dialog is closed

Tags: c#

In my project I've got 3 forms - main form, form with list of some object(in dropdownlist), form where i can add new object.

In main form I can invoke form with list of objects and form with add func. And I do it like this

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(some_param);
f2.ShowDialog();
```

When f2 is opened I can see drop down list with objects and a button to add new object(using form with add func). In this dialog I decided to add new object

```
void click1(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
  Form3 f3 = new Form3(some_param); // want to add new object and then show in dropdownlist
  f3.ShowDialog();
  radDropDownList1.Items.Clear();  // I close the form and catch here NullReferenceException
  InitDropDown();
}
```

What's the problem? What causes NullReferenceException?

When I show form3 by pressing button on main form and then close - it works normal and main form doesn't catch any exceptions when form 3 is closed.

Comment: Enable exceptions and you will see where from exceptions come. Go in Visual Studio -> Debug -> Exceptions, mark CLR Exceptions

Comment: It has helped. I've found what cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and [sll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485076/sll) comment is what helped me too. So i am just reposting his comment as an anwser so others can see this thread as solved.

**Official Answer**
Enable exceptions and you will see where from exceptions come. Go in Visual Studio -> Debug -> Exceptions, mark CLR Exceptions - [sll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485076/sll)